# How to make textbox change background color one at a time (when there are multiple textboxes) when I press enter in particular textbox?

Tags: javascript, textbox, background-color

I’m trying to figure out how to create a form with multiple rows of textboxes, whereby when participants key in their response into each textbox and press enter, the background of the textbox changes from white to black so as to hide the response that they just entered. Currently however when I press enter on the first textbox, all the textboxes change from white to black or the last textbox changes to black, instead of just the first textbox. Is there any solution for this? As the platform I’m doing it on uses a language that is javascript-based, I have tried to convert the code to javascript but I’m not sure if it’s accurate. Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
function enter(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13)
  document.getElementById("response1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function enter(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13)
  document.getElementById("response2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function enter(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13)
  document.getElementById("response3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created 3 listeners who execute when ENTER is pressed regardless of where it happened, so all 3 of them are running when you hit enter.

You need to make them aware of which element was active when ENTER was pressed, you can access it from the `event.target`, for example by their `id`:

```js
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById(event.target.id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
})
```

```html
<div><input style="text" id="one"></div>
<div><input style="text" id="two"></div>
<div><input style="text" id="three"></div>
```

You can run this snippet and hit ENTER in one or several of the text inputs

Answer (score 0):

You have the same `enter()` function on every element. No wonder that they all fire up. Try this approach:

```
function enter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   let tocolor;
   switch (e.target.name) {
     case "nameattributeoftextbox1": tocolor = "response1"; break;
     case "nameattributeoftextbox2": tocolor = "response2"; break;
...
   }
   document.getElementById(tocolor).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```